# Regular expression to match Google earth URLs

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am trying to get a regular expression that verifies that the url input a user feeds in a form is a valid google earth url. eg `https://earth.google.com/web/@18.2209311,-63.06963893,-0.67163554a,2356.53661597d,34.99999967y,358.1303302h,0t,0r`

I have tried to use js and html for verification but its not working here is the regex function that I currently have

```
var urlRegex = /^(ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9-\.]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\/?([^\s<>\#%"\,\{\}\\|\\\^\[\]`]+)?$/;
var earthRegex = /earth.google.com/;
```

and within the function I have this:

if ((linkInUrl !== '-') && !(urlRegex.test(linkInUrl) && earthRegex.test(linkInUrl))) {
return 'Please enter a valid Link URL';

Comment: The long CSV string at the end of the URL has _six_ components in the example you gave.  Would you expect _every_ URL to have the same components with the same format?

Comment: Yes that is a sample of what is expected in the url @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using the following regex pattern:

```regex
(?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/earth\.google\.com\/web\/@-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?,-\d+(?:\.\d+)?,-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?a,-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?d,-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?y,-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?h,\d+t,\d+r
```

Perhaps too long for a full explanation, but each CSV component at the end of the URL is generally matched using something like `-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?`, which will match a positive/negative integer/float number.